# How to create table in Oracle and PHP?

Tags: php, oracle

I'm trying to create a table in an Oracle database, using this code:

```
<?php
include_once("connection.php");
$conn = SQL_CONNECT();
$create_table = oci_parse($conn, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
                                    email_valid(eid int(11)     NOT NULL,
                                    email varchar2(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
                                    password varchar2(255) NOT NULL,
                                    activation varchar2(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
                                    status enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
                                    PRIMARY KEY(eid))");

$r = oci_execute($create_table) or die(oci_error()); 

?>
```

When I try to run this code, I get this error message:

`Warning: oci_execute() [function.oci-execute]: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option in C:\PORTAL\xampp\htdocs\email\create.php on line 12`

Comment: What's `$create_table`? It [might be `FALSE`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-parse.php) and you aren't checking. `var_dump( $create_table );`

Comment: its a variable i am parsing the variable and passing that to oci_execute()

Comment: You could start by looking at the [create table syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_7002.htm#SQLRF01402)... The IF NOT EXISTS is illegal in Oracle and so are enums.

Comment: I know, but how do you know it isn't `FALSE`? According to the documentation (like I linked) it can be if it caused an error (which, if you read Ben's message - it does). That way `oci_execute(false)` might output that error message. You need to only run `oci_execute` if `oci_parse` returns a statement and not `FALSE`.

Comment: And now i edited the query : $create_table = "CREATE TABLE email_valid(eid int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
            email varchar2(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
            password varchar2(255) NOT NULL,
            activation varchar2(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
            status enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0')";

Comment: And the error is : Warning: oci_execute() [function.oci-execute]: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis in C:\PORTAL\xampp\htdocs\email\create.php

Comment: is enum are valid in oracle??